# Angular 13 forms module related errors with forms module installed

Tags: angular, angular-forms

notice:

```
Error: src/app/money_makers/shochat_guts/shochat_content_creator_components/active-stream-dashboard/shochat-contentcreator-chat/shochat-contentcreator-chat.component.html:81:18 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

81                  [(ngModel)]="forminput"
```

but look at my app module

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

    imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ....
    ]
```

this error only happened when I migrated my angular 10 project to a angular 13 project.

I did this migration by starting a new angular 13 project and then moving over the `src` folder to the new angular 13 project and then installed all dependencies

why is this happening?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    
    ShochatContentcreatorChatComponent,

    ShochatDisplayToUserComponentComponent,
    ShochatUserChatComponent,
    UserSetChatnameComponent,
    ShochatUserLivevideoComponent,
    ShochatUserShochatsDisplayComponent,
    ShochatUserVideoCallComponent,
    ShochatVideoChatComponent,
    ShochatUserVideoCallActualComponent,
    ShochattimerComponent,
    UserconsomablepreviewComponent,
    CreditcardorloginaddneeedComponent,
    ContentcreatorendshochatreviewComponent,
    UserendshochatreviewComponent,
    UserFavLikesPurchaesesComponent,
    CreatorstatsComponent,
    CreatortypeindexComponent,
    ShochatshowpreviewComponent,
    EmailverifedrefreshuserloginComponent,
    ContentfeedpostsComponent,
    ContentcreatorintrovideodashboardComponent,
    ShochatEncodingHowtoComponent,
    SubscribingplaceholderComponent,
    ContentcreatorcategoriesadminComponent,
    ModeratecreatorpostsadminComponent,
    ContentfeedpostcommentsComponent,
  ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule,
      FontAwesomeModule,
      RecaptchaV3Module,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also import the `FormsModule` in the feature module which holds the component where you are using the ngModel.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule], 
  declarations:[ShowChatComponent] 
})
export class ShowChatModule {}
```

Comment: im sorry im not really clear what you mean, can you expand please?

Comment: and is this a new requirement with angular 13, 12, or 11 ?

Comment: Is the component `shochat-content-creator-chat.component` declared in the AppModule? If no, then you need to import the FormsModule in the module that is declaring ShoChatContentCreatorChat component.

Comment: if im correct from my understanding of what you said I need to also declare `@NgModel` inside the the component. Do you have a link by chance I can reference. Thank you so much

Comment: yes it is. I edited my quesiton to include the info